# Including -lcurl in makefile

Tags: c++, unix, curl

Only one of my classes (Parser) require the lcurl library. I have libcurl4-gnutls-dev installed. When I compile a class in the terminal with g++ class.cpp -lcurl, it works fine. When I try to include it in a makefile, it won't throw undefined reference errors. 
Here is my makefile, keep in mind only Parser needs it.

```
$GPP = g++ -O3 -Wall

UTILS = ../Utilities
SCANNER = ../Utilities
SCANLINE = ../Utilities

M = Main.o
E = Email.o
P = Parser.o
SL = ScanLine.o
S = Scanner.o
U = Utils.o
LDFLAGS = -lcurl 

Aprog: $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U)
    $(GPP) -o Aprog $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U)

Main.o: Main.h Main.cpp
    $(GPP) -o Main.o -c Main.cpp 

Email.o: Email.h Email.cpp
    $(GPP) -o Email.o -c Email.cpp

ParseText.o: ParseText.h ParseText.cpp
    $(GPP) -o ParseText.o -c ParseText.cpp -lcurl

ScanLine.o: $(SCANLINE)/ScanLine.h $(SCANLINE)/ScanLine.cpp
    $(GPP) -o ScanLine.o -c $(SCANLINE)/ScanLine.cpp

Scanner.o: $(SCANNER)/Scanner.h $(SCANNER)/Scanner.cpp
    $(GPP) -o Scanner.o -c $(SCANNER)/Scanner.cpp

Utils.o: $(UTILS)/Utils.h $(UTILS)/Utils.cpp
    $(GPP) -o Utils.o -c $(UTILS)/Utils.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm Aprog
echo "Clean"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run g++ with the '-c' option like this:

```
ParseText.o: ParseText.h ParseText.cpp
    $(GPP) -o ParseText.o -c ParseText.cpp -lcurl
```

The -c option means "Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.", so adding -lcurl does not do anything at all. The references to curl functions remain as unresolved references in the ParseText.o file.

You need to add -lcurl to the linking phase, which is the rule 'Aprog' in your makefile. This rule takes all of the object files from the individual translation units (ie. cpp files) and links them together, then adds linkage to any libraries you specify.

```
Aprog: $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U)
    $(GPP) -o Aprog $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U) -lcurl
```

or, since you have set the variable LDFLAGS you can use:

```
Aprog: $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U)
    $(GPP) -o Aprog $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `-lcurl` to your *link* line. In your case you specify an explicit link command (instead of relying on default rule for that) so `LDFLAGS` is not taken into account. Use:

```
Aprog: $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U)
    $(GPP) -o Aprog $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U) -lcurl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LDLIBS          = -lcurl` instead of `LDFLAGS`. If that doesn't work, put `$(LDFLAGS)` at the end of your `gcc` invocation.

```
$(GPP) -o Aprog $(M) $(E) $(P) $(SL) $(S) $(U) $(LDFLAGS)
```